# Unusual Output from Foreach()

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Okay I have been working on a website but I keep on having an odd display whenever I use a foreach loop on some data from a data base.
I get this:

```
2
Posted By: 2
22
Posted By: 2
2H
Posted By: H
HH
Posted By: H
HT
Posted By: T
TT
Posted By: T
TA
Posted By: A
AA
Posted By: A
A
```

When I use this loop:

```
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fcat`");
    $resa = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if(!empty($resa)){
        foreach($resa as $j){
            echo $j['title']."<br />";
            echo "Posted By: ".$j['poster']."<br />";
            echo $j['info'];
        }
    }else{
        echo "Nothing.";
    }
```

On this database:

```
id is an int(11)= 2
title is a varchar(65)= Hi
info is a text= Test
creator is a text= Admin
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's odd about that display? Apart from the fact that you're not outputting line-breaks between records so the title of one is getting output right next to the info of the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fcat`");
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    while($j = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        echo $j['title']."<br />";
        echo "Posted By: ".$j['poster']."<br />";
        echo $j['info'];
    }
}else{
    echo "Nothing.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array return an array with both numeric and associate key

> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )

so, change it to

```
mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fcat`");
    while($j = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        echo $j['title']."<br />";
        echo "Posted By: ".$j['poster']."<br />";
        echo $j['info'];
    }
```